# Inequality in Lp spaces with 0<p<1

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I just asked if the following inequality is correct ?

${\parallel f\parallel}_{{L}_{p}} \leq c {\parallel f\parallel}_{{L}_{2}} $

Where ${L}^{p}$ is the space of periodic real functions   on a bounded set $Q$ ,such that  $Q$$\subset $ ${R}^{3}$ with $0<p<1$ .

I am loking for a reference to the ${L}^{p}$ spaces with $0<p<1$ ? . Thanks.

Comment: The statement is not clear. The integrals in the norm taken are supposed to be over Q since the integrals over  ${R}^{3}$  are not finite, Where does periodicity come in? Anyway, the inequality follows easily from Holder's inequality when you take the integrals over Q.

Comment: $L^{p}$ spaces with $0<p<1$ are not found in basic texts because they are not normed vector spaces. They are badly behaved topological vector spaces even though they are metrizable, They have trivial dual spaces.

Comment: Here we consider the $Lp $ space of periodic functions i.e$\dot{L}p$ . In this space we can use the Fourier transform. Since $p<1$ we get $1/p$>$1$ , then ,I can't see how  to use   Holder's inequality .